# Please reverse the tag synonym involving [semantic] and [semantics]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request, tag-synonyms

I feel that the tags have been merged in the wrong direction. [semantics](/questions/tagged/semantics) is a noun, whereas [semantic](/questions/tagged/semantic) is an adjective. In my opinion, adjectives are usually unsuitable for tags, and nouns should be preferred. The one exception I can think of to this rule is when the tag describes the question itself (i.e. [subjective](/questions/tagged/subjective)), rather than what the question is about.

To summarize, the [semantic](/questions/tagged/semantic) tag suggests that the question is semantically correct, i.e. no grammar problems, whereas the [semantics](/questions/tagged/semantics) tag suggests that the question is asking about how to code semantically. I think it's pretty obvious which one is tag-deserving, and which isn't. *So please can we swap the two tags around!*

---

**Edit:** Even [the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/semantic/info) seems to think the tag is called "semantics":

> Semantics
>
> The semantics of programming languages and other languages is an important issue and area of study in computer science. Like the syntax of a language, its semantics can be defined exactly.

Comment: Well, 'semantic' is *also* the singular form of the noun... but I do agree with switching this up. Also, there is a synonym proposal pending on `[semantic]`.

Comment: @Jon Seigel: I can't actually think of a sentence where semantic is used as a singular noun. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Hmmm... now that I look at a dictionary, it doesn't list semantic as a noun (seems kind of odd), so I was wrong about that. I still agree with the reversal/merge, though.

Comment: @Jon: It's like "mathematics", "electronics", etc. I expect someone better educated than I knows what this class of nouns is called... :-)

Comment: I can definitely see an instance where a sentence would use the word 'semantic' - "An HTML tag that has no _semantic_ meaning."

Comment: @Nightfirecat: That's being used as an adjective, not a noun. I've already said that in the question.

Comment: Any follow up to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completed:

- Reversed Tag Synonym [semantics](/questions/tagged/semantics) --> [semantic](/questions/tagged/semantic) and merged to rename all tags.
- Added rudimentary tag wiki to [semantics](/questions/tagged/semantics).  Feel free to improve.

Answer (score 6):

[Semantic and semantics do not have the same meaning.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130868/please-unmerge-the-semantic-and-semantics-tag) This tag synonym should be removed, not just changed.

[Semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_%28computer_science%29) is a field of computer science that studies the meanings of programs and connects programming languages with models of computation and specifications. While computer science questions are now best asked [on the computer science site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), there are historical questions about semantics on Stack Overflow that should be tagged as such ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399648/what-happens-to-you-if-you-break-the-monad-laws)).

[Semantic](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/semantic.shtml) is a package for the Emacs editor that is used by programming language analyzers. All the questions currently tagged [emacs+semantic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semantic+emacs) refer to Semantic. There may be other meanings of this name that I am not aware of.