# Please unmerge the semantic and semantics tag

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please reverse the tag synonym involving [semantic] and [semantics]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65751/please-reverse-the-tag-synonym-involving-semantic-and-semantics)

The tags [semantic](/questions/tagged/semantic) and [semantics](/questions/tagged/semantics) are synonyms, which is weird, since this is not a noun and its plural.

[Semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_%28computer_science%29) is a field of computer science that studies the meanings of programs and connects programming languages with models of computation and specifications. While computer science questions are now best asked [on the computer science site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/), there are historical questions about semantics on Stack Overflow that should be tagged as such ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399648/what-happens-to-you-if-you-break-the-monad-laws)).

[Semantic](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/semantic.shtml) is a package for the Emacs editor that is used by programming language analyzers. All the questions currently tagged [emacs+semantic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/semantic+emacs) refer to Semantic. There may be other meanings of this name that I am not aware of.

Most uses of the merged tag are noise; they should be retagged. But please unmerge the two tags so that we can keep the legitimate uses.

Comment: @animuson No. This was requesting reversing the direction of the synonym. I am requesting the removal of the synonym. And again, this is a feature request, since I am requesting action from higher up.

Comment: So you propose having `semantic` synonimized with `emacs-semantic` or something along those lines?

Comment: @Gilles - Do we really need a new tag (on meta) for [meta-tag:tag-unmerge-request] when we already have [meta-tag:retag-request]? Also, this isn't really a feature request; no new code needs to be written: It's a [meta-tag:support] request.

Comment: @KevinVermeer I'm requesting that someone does something, I'm not requesting an answer. I've always been told this made it a [meta-tag:feature-request] and not a [meta-tag:support] question. But I'm getting tired of this argument really really fast. Retag this [meta-tag:always-monday-in-mauritius] for all I care, as long as it gets done.

Comment: I had no idea that semantic was a package for the Emacs editor. I think that suggests that the tag used for that should probably be disambiguated in some way, perhaps as suggested by Matthew: `[emacs-semantic]` At first blush, [tag:semantic] and [tag:semantics] *do* look like synonyms.