# Burninate [independent]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request

[independent](/questions/tagged/independent) has no tag wiki, and seems to mean *"my question uses the word 'independent' in the title"*, typically suggesting the asker has two pieces of code interacting with each other in strange ways.

In other cases, independent is used as a modified to another tag:

- [**dpi** + **independent**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dpi+independent)
- [**resolution** + **independent**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/resolution+independent)
- [**screen-resolution** + **independent**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/screen-resolution+independent)
- [**independent** + **set**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/independent%20set) - this seems to [warrant its own tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22independent+set%22), [independent-set](/questions/tagged/independent-set), as it seems like a fairly common topic.
- [**device** + **independent**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/device+independent)
- <s>[platform](/questions/tagged/platform) [independent](/questions/tagged/independent)</s> - moved

In some cases, the compound tag already exists (in the [more preferable noun form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/65751/147400)):

- [platform-independence](/questions/tagged/platform-independence)  (rather the the poorly named [platform-independent](/questions/tagged/platform-independent))

[image: burninate-request]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I removed the tag from all questions (54 in total), so it should be deleted automatically.

[image]