# Should we retag questions with [platform-independent] to [platform-independence]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, burninate-request

I was about to move questioned tagged [platform-independent](/questions/tagged/platform-independent) into [platform-independence](/questions/tagged/platform-independence)

However, I've realized they have subtly different (and mostly unrespected) meanings:

- [platform-independent](/questions/tagged/platform-independent) - an adjective - *"This question **is** platform-independent"*

  This describes the *question* as being generic, and not pertaining to a particular platform, in the same way as [language-agnostic](/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) describes a question as not pertaining to a particular programming language.

  This tag feels redundant - while you'd expect every programming question to be tagged with a language, and should make it clear when you don't care about the language ([language-agnostic](/questions/tagged/language-agnostic)), there's no need to specify a platform, and specifying that you don't care about the platform is implicit.
- [platform-independence](/questions/tagged/platform-independence) - a noun - *"This question **is about** platform-independence"*.

  The question is *asking* about how to write code in a way that works on multiple platforms

This ultimately comes down to the conclusion [I've made before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65751/please-reverse-the-tag-synonym-involving-semantic-and-semantics) that adjectival tags are meta-tags, and in the vast majority shouldn't exist.

---

My proposal is:

1. Work through questions tagged [platform-independent](/questions/tagged/platform-independent), and either remove the tag or retag as [platform-independence](/questions/tagged/platform-independence)
2. Having done this, burninate [platform-independent](/questions/tagged/platform-independent)

Comment: Also, what am I supposed to title this? The keyword filter forces me to start with a `.`...

Comment: I tried something (but it might not be proper English, this being Sunday and everything).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Edited the title to try and remove the implicit bias towards [platform-independent]

Comment: Do you mean the use of `[platform-independent]` as an adjective? That might indeed have biased the title a little :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Bingo

Answer (score 2):

To me, "platform-independent" sounds more proper than "platform-independence", even though you are right as far as to "platform-independent" is an adjective and "platform-independence" is a moun. Having said that, even if you retag it, folks will still try to tag with "platform-independent" because that is how it is commonly used in conversation. Or a discussion will be created requesting a retag of "platform-independence" be changed to "platform-independent".

Comment: _"folks will still try to tag with [platform-independent]"_ - not if [platform-independent] is burninated and they get offered [platform-independence]. _"Or a discussion will be created requesting a retag"_ - surely that's what this discussion is for - that'd just be marked as a duplicate of this.